# How to upload file which is already uploaded

Tags: php

There is file in the sever folder, i need to upload in in other folder.
it did try but even i cannot select file from server. Without HTML.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is or what you're asking.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you want to  move file one folder to another folder?

Comment: Thank you. I did try how to upload file to server from a server file. but i did not get any answer so i came to finale result. see in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload file from server.
So need to do Copy one folder to other folder.
Thank you.

```
copy(file,to_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

> To move file from one folder to another:

Use `rename()` function.

Example:

```
rename("user/img1.jpg", "user/otherfolder/im1.jpg");
```

This function will move the image from one folder to another.
In above example `img1.jpg` was located in `user` folder and it was moved to folder `otherfolder` in `user` folder

> To copy file from one folder to another:

Use `copy()` function.

```
copy("user/img1.jpg", "user/otherfolder/im1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename()` function:

`rename('image1.jpg', 'anotherfolder/image1.jpg');`